# How to find the image coordinates of an object in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm currently on an **image processing project using matlab**. I have to find the **exact location of these objects**. I've seperated and filtered these objects from original images but can anyone please guide how to find the **location of these objects in xy coordinates**.

[Herte is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gugsz.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html. It depends on what you want to do with these a)find location of their centroids or find all the edges. Further you have multiple blobs, so try separating them out using kmeans https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html

Comment: Since you have a lovely binary image, the best way is to use [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) to generate a labeled image. Then you can either look for the coordinates of each label, or you can pass the image to [`regionprops`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html?s_tid=doc_ta) to get the properties of each label.